# How to apply xts function per row in a dataframe

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I have a dataframe in R, and a column called created_at which holds a text which I want to parse into a datetime. Here is a snappy preview:

```
head(pushes)

    created_at repo.url                                  repository.url

1 2013-06-17T00:14:04Z                          https://github.com/Mindful/blog

2 2013-07-31T21:08:15Z          https://github.com/leapmotion/js.leapmotion.com

3 2012-11-04T07:08:15Z                       https://github.com/jplusui/jplusui

4 2012-06-21T08:16:22Z                  https://github.com/LStuker/puppet-rbenv

5 2013-03-10T09:15:51Z           https://github.com/Fchaubard/CS108FinalProject

6 2013-10-04T11:34:11Z                       https://github.com/cmmurray/soccer

  actor.login payload.actor actor_attributes.login

1                                          Mindful

2                                        joshbuddy

3                                             xuld

4                                          LStuker

5                                         ststanko

6                                         cmmurray
```

I wrote an instructions which works ok with some test data:

`xts::.parseISO8601("2012-06-17T00:14:04",tz="UTC")$first.time` returns proper Posix date

But when I apply it to a column with this instruction:

```
pushes$created_at <- xts::.parseISO8601(substr(pushes$created_at,1,nchar(pushes$created_at)-1),tz="UTC")$first.time
```

every row in a dataframe gets a duplicated date 2012-06-17 00:14:04 UTC

Like the function runned only once for the first row and then result was duplicated in rest of the rows :( Can you please help me to apply it properly row per row in a created_at column ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `.parseISO8601` is supposed to be a character string, not a vector.  You need to use `sapply` (or equivalent) to loop over your vector.

```
created_at <-
  c("2013-06-17T00:14:04Z", "2013-07-31T21:08:15Z", "2012-11-04T07:08:15Z",
    "2012-06-21T08:16:22Z", "2013-03-10T09:15:51Z", "2013-10-04T11:34:11Z")
# Only parses first element
.parseISO8601(substr(created_at,1,nchar(created_at)-1),tz="UTC")$first.time
# [1] "2013-06-17 00:14:04 UTC"
firstParseISO8601 <- function(x) .parseISO8601(x,tz="UTC")$first.time
# parse all elements
datetimes <- sapply(sub("Z$","",created_at), firstParseISO8601, USE.NAMES=FALSE)
# note that "simplifying" the output strips the POSIXct class, so we re-add it
datetimes <- .POSIXct(datetimes, tz="UTC")
```